# AWS: Clone RDS for separate EB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I want to create a copy of my `production` environment to use for `staging` on `AWS`. I'm using `Rails` with `RDS`.

I found [this information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) on how to restore from an `RDS` Snapshot but I want it to be restored to a new `RDS`, essentially get a clone of the database. Then I want to use this db copy with a clone of an `EB instance` which I will configure similarly to the production server but with the `staging` environment.

Is there a way I can clone my whole db volume and use it as a new volume with the second EB instance?

Comment: It says `You cannot restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a new DB instance is created when you restore`, isn't that what you want? `a new DB instance`

Comment: @TarunLalwani from what I understand it seems like it’ll restore a version of the db to the same instance which would be connected to the same ec2. I want a separate copy which I can use with a new ec2 instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flow is to take a snapshot

[image: Snapshot]

Then from Action click `Restore Snapshot` option

[image: Restore Snapshot]

And a new independent instance is created from the same snapshot

[image: RBD Instance]

Comment: I would suggest you open a new question and I would help you out on the same. Editing this question or answer your new query will completely change the context.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886825/create-a-testing-copy-for-ec2-eb-instance