# Create a testing copy for EC2 + EB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've my application setup on AWS (EB and EC2). My database is `PostgreSQL` and it is stored in the `EBS` service provided by AWS.

I'm going to push a major change to my application (including invasive migrations), to ensure that I don't end up losing data I want to create a copy of my whole application and update the code for that.

The steps I have till now:

1. [Clone an EB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.clone.html)
2. Create a snapshot of my `EBS` and use that to create a new volume
3. Update the configuration settings of my EB instance to point to the new volume and deploy the new code to the `EB` instance

I can't find proper documentation for how to do these things on `AWS` so I'm looking for some confirmation about the steps I have ensure that I don't end up wrecking something.

Comment: So the way it works, you create snapshot, create a new EC2 with Disk restored from that snapshot and you have a new EC2 running instance with same DB. But I would suggest if possible stop the postgresql or the instance before taking a snapshot, this will ensure the state of the DB is intact

Comment: So to clarify, in this case, the new EC2 is running on a copy of the `DB` right? And making any changes to this `DB` won't affect the original or change its contents?

Comment: Yes. no relation between the two

Comment: Okay that answers my questions, if you want to write it as an answer then I'll accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way it works, you create snapshot, create a new `EC2` with Disk restored from that snapshot and you have a new `EC2` running instance with same DB.

But I would suggest if possible stop the `postgresql` or the instance before taking a snapshot, this will ensure the state of the DB is intact.

The two `EC2` instances will have no relation and changes made in one DB will not impact the other.

Comment: Actually I've a follow up question here, I can't find a way to create a new `EC2` from the `Volume` which I created using the `Snapshot`

Comment: See this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html